I accepted the updated moderator agreement yesterday; why do I have to accept again?
Yesterday some moderators on the site I moderator accepted updated Moderator Agreement, some - declined. But as of today all these outcomes are cleared. We all see the Moderator Agreement as it's not signed or rejected before.
Is it intentional behavior due to some recent updates (I didn't hear about it though) on Agreement after its publication, or there's a bug?

There was a mistake with the initial launch of the updated Moderator Agreement where at least one paragraph did not reflect changes that had been agreed to during the discussion and review period.
Once that was pointed out, the update was rolled back, and a couple hours later a fixed version was rolled out. However, since the text of the Agreement changed between those two instances, those mods who accepted the initial, mistaken version have to re-accept the fixed version.
This was pointed out, discussed, and updated in the Teachers' Lounge.
You can compare the mistaken version at v4 of the Agreement and the fixed version at v5 of the Agreement; the relevant difference is in section v. of "The terms of the agreement".

Didn't know there's a versioning of Agreement available on the site. Thanks
